# Find Average and Final Student Grades tsvfile Python

Tags: python

The class problem.
"Write a program that reads the student information from a tab separated values (tsv) file. The program then creates a text file that records the course grades of the students. Each row of the tsv file contains the Last Name, First Name, Midterm1 score, Midterm2 score, and the Final score of a student. A sample of the student information is provided in StudentInfo.tsv. Assume the number of students is at least 1 and at most 20."

Here is what I have come up with.

```
# TODO: Declare any necessary variables here. 
import csv

open_file = input()

students = []

      
# TODO: Read a file name from the user and read the tsv file here. 

with open(open_file, newline='') as tsvfile:
    #reader = csv.reader(open_file, delimiter = '\t')
    reader = csv.DictReader(open_file)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        students.append({"last_name": row[0],
        "first_name": row[1],
        "midterm1": int(row[2]),
        "midterm2": int(row[3]),
        "final": int(row[4])})

   
# TODO: Compute student grades and exam averages, then output results to a text file here. 

for student in sorted(students, key = lambda student : student["last_name"]):
        average_score = (int(students["midterm1"]) + int(students["midterm2"]) + int(students["final"])) / 3
        
        num_students = len(students)    
        midterm1_average += student.get("midterm1", 0)
        midterm2_average +=  student.get("midterm2", 0)
        final_average += student("final", 0)
    
        if average_socre >= 90:
            student.append('A')
    
        elif average_score >= 80:
            student.append('B')
    
        elif average_score >= 70:
            student.append('C')
    
        elif average_score >= 60:
            student.append('D')
    
        else:
            student.append('F')
        students.append
        
        num_of_students = len(students)
        midterm1_average /= num_of_students
        midterm2_average /= num_of_students
        final_average /= num_of_students




print(students)
```

I'm just trying to get the code to work for a start. I error out with a key IndexError. See I expect the program to reference [0] from the first last name in the tsv file and so on.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    students.append({"last_name": row[0],
KeyError: 0
```

```
Barrett    Edan    70  45  59
Bradshaw    Reagan  96  97  88
Charlton    Caius   73  94  80
Mayo    Tyrese  88  61  36
Stern    Brenda  90  86  45
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues,

1. your reader does not read the file. instead it reads the path to the file.
2. your using csv.DictReader now instead of csv.reader. which means

   1. you should specify the delimiter on csv.DictReader
   2. you should specify the fieldnames on csv.DictReader
   3. you should access the reader with those fieldnames rather then the index.
      so `row["last_name"]` instead of `row[0]`
   4. csv.DictReader can read fieldnames from your tsv file. so you might choose not to skip the headerline and let csv.DictReader get the fieldnames from the tsvfile. I am not showing that below because your sample doesn't show a headerline.

Ideally you could now write something like the following:

```py
fieldnames = ['last_name', 'first_name', 'midterm1', 'midterm2', 'final']
with open(open_file, newline="") as tsvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t", fieldnames=fieldnames)
    next(reader) # are you skipping the headerline?
    students = list(reader)
```

However you also want to convert the midterms and final exams to ints.

```py
fieldnames = ['last_name', 'first_name', 'midterm1', 'midterm2', 'final']
exams = ["midterm1", "midterm2", "final"]
with open(open_file, newline="") as tsvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t", fieldnames=fieldnames)
    next(reader) # are you skipping the headerline?
    for student in reader:
        student.update({exam: int(student[exam]) for exam in exams})
        students.append(student)
```

Comment: I'm starting over. I'll report back, when it is less messy. I'm not going to use DictReader or the newline="" argument. Rather stick to basic 'r', and 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

Managed it. Passed what the online book wanted with some instructor help.

I do wish I had an idea of how to make it cleaner as in, put the if/elif loop outside the write and read to free up memory space. Then append the grades as a fifth created column and the Averages for each score column.

The code is also written the way it is as a beginner. The basics mind you.

No fancy dictreader here.

```
# TODO: Declare any necessary variables here. 
import csv

open_file = input().strip()

students = []
last_names = []
first_names = []
midterm1_score = []
midterm2_score = []
final_score = []

      
# TODO: Read a file name from the user and read the tsv file here. 

with open(open_file, 'r') as f1:
    contents = list(csv.reader(f1, delimiter='\t'))
    for line in contents:
        # Separate columns
        last_name ="".join(line[0])
        first_name ="".join(line[1])        
        midterm1 ="".join(line[2])
        midterm2 ="".join(line[3])
        final ="".join(line[4])
        
         #Append to Declared Lists
        students.append(line)
        last_names.append(last_name)
        first_names.append(first_name)
        midterm1_score.append(int(midterm1))
        midterm2_score.append(int(midterm2))
        final_score.append(int(final))

# TODO: Compute student grades and exam averages, then output results to a text file here.
with open('report.txt', 'w') as f3:
    for i in range(len(midterm1_score)):
       
        average_score = (midterm1_score[i] + midterm2_score[i] + final_score[i]) // 3
        midterm1_average = sum(midterm1_score) / len(midterm1_score)
        midterm2_average = sum(midterm2_score) / len(midterm2_score)
        final_average = sum(final_score) / len(final_score)
    
        grade = ""
        
        if average_score >= 90:
            grade = 'A'
        
        elif average_score >= 80:
            grade = 'B'
                
        elif average_score >= 70:
            grade = 'C'
        
        elif average_score >= 60 :
            grade = 'D'
        
        else:
            grade = 'F'
        
        print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(last_names[i],
        first_names[i],
        midterm1_score[i],
        midterm2_score[i],
        final_score[i],
        grade), file = f3)

    print("\nAverages: midterm1 {:.2f}, midterm2 {:.2f}, final {:.2f}".format(midterm1_average, midterm2_average, final_average), file = f3)
```